# How to destroy beans in correct order (session and singleton scopes used)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm developing a web app with Spring that have two types of bean scopes - singleton and session. Session level beans are using different services provided by singletons. One of those services is responsible for cleaning up files from user session. This works correctly under normal usage, but it fails when the app is being shut down. Session level beans are destroyed AFTER singletons. This means that session bean request service which is already destroyed.

Required bean destroy order for my app is:

- Session scoped beans;
- Singleton beans.

I have already tried DependsOn annotation to describe dependencies, but it doesn't work the way I need. With the annotation (also with @Order) I can control order of creation and destruction only within singleton beans.

Also, my web app configuration is entirely annotation based.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround for this was creation of session manager service.
This services monitors sessions and on `@PreDestroy` event invalidates all registered sessions which destroys all session scoped objects. Now everything cleans up nicely.